# How do I know my full node is "strong"?

Tags: iri-node

I just got a full node setup and have 3 neighbors. Things are flowing and we are exchanging new transactions. Are there some metrics I can get from the node to know whether it's "strong" or if there is more it can be doing for the network?

The node is running at an avg of 25% cpu and using 3 of 8GB RAM. Here are some stats:

**get_neighbors()**

> address: xxxx:14265
>   numberOfAllTransactions: 180727
>   numberOfRandomTransactionRequests: 7338
>   numberOfNewTransactions: 9231
>   numberOfInvalidTransactions: 0
>   numberOfSentTransactions: 206236
>   connectionType: udp

**get_node_info()**

> appName: IRI
>   appVersion: 1.4.1.6
>   duration: 0
>   jreAvailableProcessors: 4
>   jreFreeMemory: 927601584
>   jreMaxMemory: 1960837120
>   jreTotalMemory: 1960837120
>   jreVersion: 1.8.0_151
>   latestMilestoneIndex: 332528
>   latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex: 332528
>   neighbors: 3
>   packetsQueueSize: 0
>   time: 1516570823527
>   tips: 5678
>   transactionsToRequest: 175

Comment: What do you mean by *"strong"*?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I put it in quotes. What makes 1 node run better than another? If that doesn't make sense then I guess that's the answer to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two values:

- `latestMilestoneIndex`
- `latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex`

obtained with `getNodeInfo` api call, are the only meaningful measures that counts.

For a well running full node:

- `latestMilestoneIndex` has to be updated to the last index validated by the coordinator (e.g. you can find this value on #botbox channel on Discord);
- `latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex` has to be equal to `latestMilestoneIndex` that is their difference has to be `0`.

The full node that satisfies the two conditions above is a full node synchronized with the Tangle. The Tangle needs synchronized full nodes that run 24/7.

Time after time full nodes will be affected by an increase of transactions per seconds or by changes in neighbors quality and quantity but as far as they will succeed in satisfing the two conditions above they remain well running nodes with well sized amount of CPU and memory and a good set of neighbors.

Comment: when the network increases its transactions per second, won't other factors like amount of CPU and memory matter? Does having diverse globally distributed neighbors also make for a stronger network, or does that not matter?

Comment: @Matt I answered your questions editing my post.